# import statement causing references to the .d.ts file no longer works

Tags: typescript

I have three .d.ts files, like the following.

```
types
├── index.d.ts
├── module.d.ts
└── module2.d.ts
```

I want to extend babel-types JSX.Element on my .d.ts file, so I wrote `import { JSX } from 'babel-types` in module.d.ts file.

```
/** module.d.ts */
import { JSX } from 'babel-types'

declare namespace MyApp {
    interface ExtendJSX extends JSX.Element {}
}
```

But when I do that, the module2.d.ts file report an error: "Cannot find name 'ExtendJSX'".

```
/** module2.d.ts */
/// <reference path="module.d.ts" />

declare namespace MyApp {
    function returnJSXElement (): ExtendJSX
                                  ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

```
/** index.d.ts */
/// <reference path="module.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="module2.d.ts" />

export = MyApp
```

How can I resolve this?

====== UPDATE: ======

I tried to use triple-slash directives but I got a new error: "Cannot find namespace 'JSX'."

```
/** module.d.ts */
// import { JSX } from 'babel-types'
/// <reference types="babel-types" />

declare namespace MyApp {
    interface ExtendJSX extends JSX.Element {}
                                ^^^
}
```

Comment: `babel-types` just exports `JSX` as a module type. It does not contain any `Element` member - check its types: `npm pack @types/babel-types` -> index.d.ts. Do you mean the global `JSX.Element` from `react`? You wouldn't have to import anything then.

Comment: @ford04 Thanks for your comment. I use `<reference types="react" />` instead of `import { JSX } from 'babel-types'`.